# How to separate dateRange start and end using v-model in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, calendar

I use functional calendar, and I want to save only the dateRange into two separate variables.

```
 <functional-calendar
        v-model="calendar_data"
        :sundayStart="false"
        :configs="calendar_configs"
 ></functional-calendar>
```

The calendar_data looks like this:

```
{ "currentDate": "2022-07-18T19:43:49.389Z", "selectedDate": false, "selectedDateTime": false, "selectedHour": "00", "selectedMinute": "00", "selectedDatesItem": "", "selectedDates": [], "dateRange": { "start": "7/18/2022", "end": "7/21/2022" }, "multipleDateRange": [] }
```

Comment: from where do you get `calendar_data`? is it from the API or from the props?

Comment: @Shreeraj  from the props